# Database design for user geo location

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a user management system. I need to save use geo data, ip location and so on.

Should I be creating a new table or should i just save all the data in one table column ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one user can have more than a geo data item, you need an extra table.

If one user can have one and just one geo data item, add columns to the user's table.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah the user will have more than one geo location. I need to save each piece of data in my database.